# What are the correct steps to upgrade Rails 2.3.11 to 2.3.15?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the [recent security patch](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/8/Rails-3-2-11-3-1-10-3-0-19-and-2-3-15-have-been-released/) for Rails, what are the correct steps that should be taken to successfully update Rails 2.3.11 to 2.3.15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Run your tests and make sure everything works
- Open up a new branch through git (`git checkout -b new_rails`)
- Change Rails 2.3.11 to 2.3.15 in your Gemfile
- Change RAILS_GEM_VERSION to '2.3.15' in environment.rb
- Run `bundle update rails`
- Run the tests and see if everything still works
- If not, reverse back to the old branch by doing `git checkout master`; optionally delete the new branch by doing `git branch -D new_rails`

Doing it only on the new branch ensures nothing breaks.

Comment: how to I prevent updates on other existing gems? I've inherited a (mostly) untested app and don't have much coverage and want to prevent other gems from updating versions. Do I need to specify the version in the gemfile.lock file in my gemfile for each gem?

Comment: @Paul By just running `bundle update rails` it will only update rails and its dependencies. Running `bundle` would update/install everything in your gemfile. Refer to [this bundle guide](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-update.1.html), section "UPDATING A LIST OF GEMS". In any case, do all this in a new branch, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I had to also change the RAILS_GEM_VERSION to '2.3.15' in environment.rb

Comment: @Paul Thanks! I included that in the answer so we have everything in one place.